# Is there a way to restart apache ignoring ssl certificate errors?

Tags: apache-2.4, mod-ssl, ssl-certificate-errors

My server has lots of virtualhosts, many client's domains come and go pretty frequently, and sometimes it's difficult to act quickly, finding the culprit (usually a dismissed domain) and restart apache without errors.
For example last night apache restarted but there was an error in the log file of one of the virtualhosts:

```
[error] Unable to configure RSA server private key
[error] SSL Library Error: 185073780 error:0B080074:x509 certificate
```

I deleted the virtualhost and apache restarted, but I would prefer if such events could throw only warnings and not prevent apache from restarting, I'm wondering if there's some option for ignoring those.

Comment: This is the XY problem - if a client's domain is retired it should be removed. And if it hasn't been removed you won't get these errors anyway.

Answer (score 2):

A missing TLS certificate / private key is a hard configuration error that Apache httpd can't ignore or resolve gracefully (for example by using a built-in default).

Only lower level configuration errors, the ones that result in warnings with`[warn]` or `[notice]` priorities, can be ignored  won't prevent Apache httpd from starting. (for example a *"[warn] server certificate CommonName (CN) `www.example.com' does NOT match server name"* )

If your work-flow is prone to result in such inconsistencies:

1. Improve/automate your work-flow to avoid those
2. Train yourself to run something like `apachectl configtest` after making changes
3. Add such a `apachectl configtest` test result in your monitoring and alerting so you  get warned before  a configuration error becomes a problem.